# Error on Android Studio while testing app

Tags: java, android

So I was programing on Android Studio made the app without any error but when I tried to Debug the app doesnt work :(

This is my **MainActivity**:Deleted

Comment: Remove `= new TextView(this)` in both of the TextView declaration lines. You can't instantiate a View outside of a method, and you don't need to initialize them there anyway.

Comment: @ Mike M Thanks Bro !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to change the following:

```
TextView Display1 = new TextView(this);
TextView Display2 = new TextView(this);
```

to:

```
TextView Display1;
TextView Display2;
```

You're trying to pass an instance of your activity before it's initialized.

Also, you do the following:

```
Display1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
Display1.setText(Integer.toString(vida1));

Display2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt2);
Display2.setText(Integer.toString(vida2));
```

Which, had your previous assignment been valid, replaces the instances you were trying to create with instances from your layout.  No need to try and put something there only to replace it.

Comment: You still need to declare them. You don't want to completely remove those lines.

Comment: Right, I suppose I should explicitly state that.